# Kafka config file jaas.conf not found when running spark in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, jaas

i'm having this error when i'm trying to run my spark job in cluter deploy mode. Indeed, the kafka jaas conf file is not found. Initially this file was on the edge node running the spark job when i was using the client deploy mode. I put this file on hdfs since i want to run the job in cluster mode but i'm still facing this issue : 
**Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: hdfs://dev3hdp/opt/wmb/kafka/conf/kafka_client_jaas.conf (No such file or directory)**

my spark submit conf is :

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--name my_job \
--class org.my.main.class \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--queue $QUEUE \
--jars $KAFKA_JARS \
--files $PATH_KAFKA_CLIENT_JAAS_CONF,$KEY_PATH \
--driver-memory 6g \
--executor-memory 4g \
--executor-cores 2 \
--num-executors 2 \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config="$KAFKA_CLIENT_JAAS_CONF_FILENAME \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config="$KAFKA_CLIENT_JAAS_CONF_FILENAME \
--conf spark.hadoop.hive.llap.daemon.service.hosts="@llap0" \
--conf spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url=$HIVESERVER2_INTERACTIVE_JDBC_URL \
--conf spark.datasource.hive.warehouse.metastoreUri=$METASTORE_URI \
--conf spark.datasource.hive.warehouse.load.staging.dir="/tmp" \
--conf spark.hadoop.hive.zookeeper.quorum=$ZOOKEEPER_SERVER \
--driver-java-options "\
-Dkafka.bootstrap.servers=\"$KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_EXTERNAL\" \
-Dkafka.topic=\"$KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME\" \
-Dspark.executor.instances=$SPARK_INSTANCE \
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=\"$PATH_KAFKA_CLIENT_JAAS_CONF\" \
\
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

`PATH_KAFKA_CLIENT_JAAS_CONF` variable is relative to where you've ran spark-submit, but that's not going to be the same path when code is running on external YARN machine.

More specifically, HDFS typically has no /opt path

Refer to the file by only its name in the `-D` flags, otherwise review Spark documentation on how you can use `#` symbol in the `files` flag to relocate HDFS file placement on the executors

Comment: In fact, i created the path /opt on HDFS. But I solved my problem using "#" symbol, the files can be on the edge node even if cluster deploy mode is used

Comment: You shouldn't need to create extra HDFS paths unless you do want static files for your clients. In which case, the files option to spark isn't necessary